# Python code with Input() given syntax error in Sublime REPL, but works with Python Shell

Tags: python, sublimetext3, sublimetext, python-2.x

I typed a piece of code in python 3 and the python shell runs it extremely well and gives the right output. I transfered this code to Sublime Text 3, downloaded the package sublime REPL, and I used it to run my code. However, it tells me there is a syntax error when I run it and enter an input in Sublime using REPL. Here's the line where it finds the syntax error:

```
dataGiven = sorted([float(x) for x in input("Enter data separated by a space (At least 3 values of data must be entered) ").split()])
```

But, there is no syntax error because the python shell runs the code properly. Please help. I find Sublime text to be really helpful but it just wont run properly because of this input. I am willing to post a bigger segment of the code if you need it. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

screenshot of error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Untitled.py", line 708, in <module>
    dataGiven = sorted([float(x) for x in input("Enter data separated by a space (At least 3 values of data must be entered) ").split()])
  File "<string>", line 1
    78 67 45
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

***Repl Closed***
```

Comment: So it allows you to enter an input and then it throws the syntax error? Some more code/screenshot of the error might be helpful

Comment: Sure. I'll do that. It might be a little hard to understand. Is that fine?

Comment: @Jonathan Porter Wait... the error is in that line alone. That particular line alone if run in sublime text's REPL, it generates a syntax error. I have posted a screenshot of the error in my question now. Please look at it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like Sublime is running it using a Python 2 interpreter. `input` tries to `eval` the string entered in Python 2, which is about the only way to get `SyntaxError` at runtime (because most arbitrary user entered strings aren't syntactically legal Python code). Try changing your code to:

```
import sys
print(sys.version_info)
```

which will tell you the actual version it's being run as. If it's Python 2, and you need it to run on Python 2 like it does on Python 3, switch to the `raw_input` function, or to mask away the version differences, add:

```
if sys.version_info < (3,):
    input = raw_input
```

to the top of your file to replace `input` with `raw_input` on Python 2, so it behaves like it does on Python 3.

Comment: I did that. The version is 2.7 but the code still results in a syntax error when I use the conditional statement that you provided. Anything else I can do?

Comment: @BOi: It wouldn't result in any error if you put that at the top level of your file, near the top of the file (before using the `input` function). You've missed something.

Comment: I'm sorry but that's exactly what I did. I put i right at the top of the file. However, it still generates an error. I'm not sure why.

Comment: Also I had an input() just before the line i have added in my answer. It executed without any errors.

Comment: @BOi: You entered legal Python code for the first one, that's all. The error in your screenshot is *exactly* what you'd expect from Py2 `input`. It tried to `eval` the string `"902 92 29"` as if it were a Python expression, and the error occurs when it sees the `92` separate from the `902`, with no operator in between. You need to post a [MCVE] in your question that shows what you've got. If you redefined `input` to `raw_input` in the same (or an outer) scope of where you use `input`, before you call it, this problem **would not happen**, and I can't psychically intuit what you've done wrong.

Comment: Oh. I see what you mean. It worked now. Thanks a lot. I misunderstood what you said. I really appreciate your help. Sorry about the misunderstanding.

Comment: I have another question. I have edited the previous question. Would greatly appreciate it if u answered.

Comment: @BOi: That's a completely different question; don't change your existing question completely after the fact, make a new question focused solely on the new problem. That said, two seconds on Google gave me this: https://coderwall.com/p/nhq2gg/setting-up-sublimerepl-with-python3

Comment: I tried that but I cant seem to find main.sublime-menu in my computer.